# Problem with ConTeXt (MkIV), Hebrew and ligatures

Tags: context-mkiv, ligatures, hebrew

Since I last played with the latest ConTeXt MkIV, there has been introduced this new feature. It now seems to combine Hebrew characters automatically when possible to ligatures. So for example. If I have a word with following two characters:

- U+05D5 (HEBREW LETTER VAV)
- U+05BC (HEBREW POINT DAGESH OR MAPIQ)

ConTeXt will combine these to:

- U+FB35 (HEBREW LETTER VAV WITH DAGESH)

However, I would need to disable this feature for a number of reasons. For example, this breaks my little database query, because the query key is changed before(?) macro gets it.

So if somebody would know how to turn this off and maybe also that what has changed.

Comment: If you know the name of the open type feature for such ligature, then disabling the feature is as simple as `\subff{...}`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).